# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS authentification not working on a remote ubuntu machine

Tags: java, ubuntu

When I run the documentation example on my local machine (windows) I setup the environment variable pointing to the json file and it works. If the path is incorrect it will warn me that the file is not found also.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.AudioConfig;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SsmlVoiceGender;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SynthesisInput;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SynthesizeSpeechResponse;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.VoiceSelectionParams;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Google Cloud TextToSpeech API sample application. Example usage: mvn package exec:java
 * -Dexec.mainClass='com.example.texttospeech.QuickstartSample'
 */
public class QuickstartSample {

  /** Demonstrates using the Text-to-Speech API. */
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create()) {
      // Set the text input to be synthesized
      SynthesisInput input = SynthesisInput.newBuilder().setText("Hello, World!").build();

      // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml voice gender
      // ("neutral")
      VoiceSelectionParams voice =
          VoiceSelectionParams.newBuilder()
              .setLanguageCode("en-US")
              .setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
              .build();

      // Select the type of audio file you want returned
      AudioConfig audioConfig =
          AudioConfig.newBuilder().setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.MP3).build();

      // Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected voice parameters and
      // audio file type
      SynthesizeSpeechResponse response =
          textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice, audioConfig);

      // Get the audio contents from the response
      ByteString audioContents = response.getAudioContent();

      // Write the response to the output file.
      try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.mp3")) {
        out.write(audioContents.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#windows

When I run the same jar in a remote machine (Ubuntu) and setup the environment variable. It throws this error whatever. Even if I purposely setup a wrong location.
What am I missing? Where can I look?

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials
> are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute
> Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file
> defining the credentials. See
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
> for more information.

Answer (score 0):

the mistake I made was to type two commands.

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/file.json
java -jar project.jar
```

instead of

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/file.json java -jar project.jar
```